# Contact Form 7: Mail-tag with a custom file upload button

Tags: wordpress, input, tags, label, contact-form-7

I made a custom label element with a `for` attribute attached to a file input element, and put it in the Form tab :

```
<label for="file-upload" class="label-file-upload">Choose a file</label>
<input id="file-upload" type="file">
```

I can upload a file but I don't know which mail-tag I have to put in the Mail tab in order to send it. I tried this :

```
[file-upload]
```

But it of course doesn't work. I suppose I have to add a form-tag in my code but I don't know how..

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I ve found a solution:

```
<label for="file-upload" class="label-file-upload">Choose a file</label>
[file file-upload class:file-upload id:file-upload limit:2mb filetypes:jpg|zip|rar|doc|pdf|xls|docx|xlsx]
```

Mail-tag:

```
[file-upload]
```